# Local HTML website hosted by XAMPP is not reachable when domain name is used instead of the local IP address in local network

Tags: html, apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I have hosted a HTML webpage using XAMPP in LAN; I am able to access the webpage from other computers present in the same local network when I use `http://IP address:port` but unable to access it when I use a custom domain name.

My host file looks like this.

```
    192.168.1.24:90    cohab.com
```

My httpd-vhosts.config looks as follows.

```
    <VirtualHost 192.168.1.24:90>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@www.cohab.com
    ServerName www.cohab.com
    ServerAlias cohab.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cohab"
    </VirtualHost>
```

My HTML file is present in `C:/xampp/htdocs/cohab directory`. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: is Apache listening on port 90? Be sure the line `Listen 90` is present in your ports.conf file.

Comment: Yes I have made those changes already,I have set up Listen 90